# Laravel best way to setup state for update, create and list mode in one view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a single `form.blade.php` that I use to create and modify data. In that form, sometimes I have to display additional fields only in the editing state, while in the creation state they should be hidden.
I tried to define variable `$mode` with values `edit` and `create` in each method and it works ok. From a developer's point of view this seems like a bad solution and I wanted to consult with you on how I could do it in a better way

**What i do in controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $tag = Tag::find($id);
    $mode = 'edit';

    return view('tag.edit', compact('tag', 'mode'));
}

public function create()
{
    $tag = new Tag();
    $mode = 'create';
    return view('tag.create', compact('tag', 'mode'));
}
```

**And than in form.blade**

```
@if($mode == 'edit')
   ....
@else 
   ....
@endif
```

Do you think there is a better way to do this?

Comment: you can split it up in parts and then use `@includeIf` το include them conditionally

Comment: You can avoid  `new Tag()` on create. Just send the $tag on edit and check if it's empty or not . In blade file, if  `empty($tag)` returns true it means it's in create mode, else in edit mode.

Comment: @JugalK yes that is the some way but shorter and litle elagant.

Comment: @apokryfos you think to split edit and create views?

Comment: You would have your main view which has all bits that are common to both create and edit, and you'd have two more views that have all bits that are exclusive to either create or edit and those you include conditionally using `@includeWhen` (documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#including-subviews))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the create and edit mode are separate, you can send the mode right when you include the form blade

tag.edit.blade.php

```
@include('tag.form', ['mode' => 'edit'])
```

tag.create.blade.php

```
@include('tag.form', ['mode' => 'create'])
```

So you dont have to specify it in the controller.